# how I can get out some numbers of links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problems in jquery

I have a problem which is how I can get out some numbers of links

I just want from the table

```
id=1293399
id=609876
id=6789234
id=3421
```

Of the following links

```
href="/inedx.php?form=11732&id=1293399&min=info_custom
href="/inedx.php?form=11732&id=609876&min=info_custom
href="/inedx.php?form=11732&id=6789234&min=info_custom
href="/inedx.php?form=11732&id=3421&min=info_custom
```

Experimented with this,
But I could not get them properly

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#ABC tr").each(function(){
        var A = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').find('a').attr("href");
        var B = $(A).match(/[\d]+/d);
        alert(B);
        });
    });
</script>




<body> 
<table id='ABC' border='2'>
<tr>
<td><a href='href="/inedx.php?form=11732&id=1293399&min=info_custom'>AAAy</a></td>
<td>BBB</td>
<td>CCC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href='href="/inedx.php?form=11732&id=609876&min=info_custom'>AAAy</a></td>
<td>BBB</td>
<td>CCC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href='href="/inedx.php?form=11732&id=6789234&min=info_custom'>AAAy</a></td>
<td>BBB</td>
<td>CCC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href='href="/inedx.php?form=11732&id=3421&min=info_custom'>AAAy</a></td>
<td>BBB</td>
<td>CCC</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

How do I get this only

```
id=1293399
id=609876
id=6789234
id=3421
```

Comment: What is the current result of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another answer that doesnt depend on the position id param :

```
$(function() {
    $("#ABC tr").each(function() {
        var url = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').find('a').attr("href");
        alert("id="+getURLParam("id", url));
    });
});

function getURLParam(name, url) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(url);
    if (results == null) return "";
    else return results[1];
}​
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/44rFm/1/

**note:**
logic borrowed from implementation of gup() function given in http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

Comment: +1 for robust query parameter matching, and for references. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
var A = "...",
    link = A,
    num = link.match(/id=(\d+)/);
num[0];  //"id="+number
num[1];  //only number

var B = num[0];
//Hey I just met you,
//and this is crazy,
//But here's your B,
//so use it maybe. :D
```

MDN: [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Live demo: *[`http://jsfiddle.net/zBspF/`](http://jsfiddle.net/zBspF/)*

Comment: If you want to get an array of results from `match()`, don't you need the `g` flag?

Comment: OK. I believed a bogus web tutorial.

Comment: @LarsH - `.match` by default will always return an Array, according to the MDN.

Comment: nice..short and succinct +1

Comment: +1. Would be easier to use, though, if you said `A` instead of `link`, or else `link = A;`, to connect your code to the OP's.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly hacky approach

```
var B= "id="+A.split("&id=")[1].split("&")[0];
```

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uGrPT/

Comment: Interesting, although I believe it will fail in the (unlikely?) event that the `id` query parameter is first. E.g. in `href="/inedx.php?id=1293399&form=11732&...`

Comment: @LarsH fair comment. I've added another solution below which handles this too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
  /*var id = href.substring(href.indexOf('&') + 1, href.lastIndexOf('&'));*/
    var id = href.match(/id=\d+/g);
    $('body').append(id).append('<br>') //append to body
   //alert(id)
   })
});
```

​
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BYEV9/7/)

Comment: why voting down? mid to explain?

Comment: This solution only works if the id is the first query parameter.. will fail if the ID is located anywhere else

Comment: Looks like nobody likes `.match`... and prefer the long way to do it.

Comment: fair enough, thats why I didnt downvote but it IS hard-coding,not a really nice solution.

Comment: @Derek, I used `match()` (independently of your answer).

Comment: @Derek change to using `match`

Comment: @slier if you're gonna rewrite your answer's logic completely, then delete and add another answer.Else, the comments become context-less.

Comment: @slier - Or cross out the old code then put the new code under it.

Answer (score 0):

`attr()` returns the attribute value, so `A` is the href string. `$(A)` would then look for a node using the href string as a jquery selector -- surely that's not what you want to do.

I would change the regexp match line to:

```
var B = A.match(/id=\d+/);
```

Comment: Limitation: this will match parts of the first query parameter whose name ends with `id` and whose value starts with a digit. So if you have `...?pid=26hrumph&userid=bar&id=938`, the result will be `id=26`.